# Expo React Native Error: Element type is invalid: Expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I am beginner at React Native so I am using Expo and trying to add React Navigation Bar. I am keeping on getting this error however I am exporting App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {NavigationNativeContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack"

import SignUp from "./screens/SignupScreen"
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen"
import LoadingScreen from "./screens/LoadingScreen"
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen"

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// <View style={styles.container}>
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationNativeContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={SignUp}>
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="login" component={LoginScreen}>
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationNativeContainer>

  );
}
```

THE COMPONENT WHICH I AM TRYING TO USE IS FOR EXAMPLE LOGINSCREE.JS BELOW IS THE CODE

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';


// <View style={styles.container}>
export default function LoginScreen(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">

                <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="black" barStyle="light-content" />
                <Image style={styles.logoStyle} source={require('../assets/logoBlack.png')} />


                <Text style={styles.subIntro}>Proceed with your</Text>
                <Text style={styles.intro}> Login</Text>


                <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
                    underlineColor=""

                    label="Email" mode="flat" />
                <TextInput style={styles.textInpStyle} theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
                    label="Password" mode="flat" />
                <Button style={styles.btnStyle} mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
                    SIGN IN
  </Button>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text  onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate("signup")}  style={styles.subText} >I'm a new user <Text style={styles.spIn}> Sign Up</Text> </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        </>
    );
}
```

THE ERROR I GET IS

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `App`.

```
This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue**
```

Comment: Is anyone that can help me with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

Replace `App.js` with following code :

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Replace `LoginScreen.js` with this code :

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import { Button, TextInput } from "react-native-paper";

function LoginScreen(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
        <StatusBar
          style="light"
          backgroundColor="black"
          barStyle="light-content"
        />
        <Image
          style={styles.logoStyle}
          source={require("../assets/logoBlack.png")}
        />

        <Text style={styles.subIntro}>Proceed with your</Text>
        <Text style={styles.intro}> Login</Text>

        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInpStyle}
          theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          underlineColor=""
          label="Email"
          mode="flat"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInpStyle}
          theme={{ colors: { primary: "red" } }}
          label="Password"
          mode="flat"
        />
        <Button
          style={styles.btnStyle}
          mode="contained"
          onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}
        >
          SIGN IN
        </Button>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text
            onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("signup")}
            style={styles.subText}
          >
            I'm a new user <Text style={styles.spIn}> Sign Up</Text>{" "}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
});
```

Then Create a Folder called `navigation` where you `App.js` is located
Then Inside `navigation` folder create a file called `AppNavigator.js`
Then inside `AppNavigator.js` paste this code :

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import SignUp from "./screens/SignupScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import LoadingScreen from "./screens/LoadingScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={SignUp}></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="login" component={LoginScreen}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: Perfecto. Thankyou so much. It was really helpful it solved my error I was almost shutting down until you saved me.